# MySQL выборка данных

Tags: запрос, mysql

Здравствуйте.    
Есть такой запрос.

```
SELECT hub.id, city_play.city_play, dictors1.name, dictors2.name, dictors3.name,
type_pay.type_pay, type_play.type_play, type_rolik.type_rolik,  zakaz.fio, 
zakaz.name_organization, zakaz.requisites,
zakaz.mail,zakaz.phone,
Tickets.text, Tickets.original_text, Tickets.date_end, Tickets.wishes_text,  
Tickets.price,
Tickets.date_begin, Tickets.date_pay, Tickets.chrono, Tickets.name_video,      
Tickets.type_chrono , hub.user_id FROM hub 
INNER JOIN city_play ON hub.city_play_id=city_play.id
INNER JOIN  dictors AS dictors1 ON hub.dictors_id = dictors1.id
INNER JOIN  dictors AS dictors2 ON hub.dictors_id2 = dictors2.id
INNER JOIN  dictors AS dictors3 ON hub.dictors_id3 = dictors3.id
INNER JOIN type_pay ON hub.type_pay_id = type_pay.id
INNER JOIN type_play ON hub.type_play_id = type_play.id
INNER JOIN type_rolik ON hub.type_rolik_id = type_rolik.id
INNER JOIN zakaz ON hub.zakaz_id = zakaz.id
INNER JOIN Tickets ON hub.id = Tickets.id
Order by hub.id
```

Как сделать так, чтобы он выводил только такие данные, где `hub.id = 5`, например?
Делал так, вышла ошибка:

```
From hub Where hub.id = 5
```

Спасибо за помощь.

Comment: Если именно этот запрос, то будет что-то такое:
  
    ...
    INNER JOIN Tickets ON hub.id = Tickets.id
    WHERE hub.id = 5
    Order by hub.id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT hub.id, city_play.city_play, dictors1.name, dictors2.name, dictors3.name,
type_pay.type_pay, type_play.type_play, type_rolik.type_rolik,  zakaz.fio, 
zakaz.name_organization, zakaz.requisites,
zakaz.mail,zakaz.phone,
Tickets.text, Tickets.original_text, Tickets.date_end, Tickets.wishes_text,  
Tickets.price,
Tickets.date_begin, Tickets.date_pay, Tickets.chrono, Tickets.name_video,      
Tickets.type_chrono , hub.user_id FROM hub 
INNER JOIN city_play ON hub.city_play_id=city_play.id
INNER JOIN  dictors AS dictors1 ON hub.dictors_id = dictors1.id
INNER JOIN  dictors AS dictors2 ON hub.dictors_id2 = dictors2.id
INNER JOIN  dictors AS dictors3 ON hub.dictors_id3 = dictors3.id
INNER JOIN type_pay ON hub.type_pay_id = type_pay.id
INNER JOIN type_play ON hub.type_play_id = type_play.id
INNER JOIN type_rolik ON hub.type_rolik_id = type_rolik.id
INNER JOIN zakaz ON hub.zakaz_id = zakaz.id
INNER JOIN Tickets ON hub.id = Tickets.id
WHERE hub.id = 5
Order by hub.id
```

Comment: О, спасибо большое.  
Не знал, что `WHERE hub.id = 5` в конце надо писать.